# Best way to test routes for Web API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I want to write unit tests to test that routes are able to be called in my routeconfig.cs. What is the best approach to do this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RelativeURL",
            url: "{*relativeURL}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Foo" }
            );
```

For example how would I test that the above route works via unit tests?

Comment: @Nkosi Is there a way to do this without introducing more classes?

Comment: The web api framework handles the route mapping. During unit test the web api framework is not running. So unless you plan on doing integration tests on a running version of the server then you will have to use classes to basically fake what the server does to match routes